# How is it called when one supress prepositions?

Tags: american-english

How is it called in English when one uses "Corruption patterns smart detection" instead of "Smart detection of corruption patterns"?

Is this an example of direct versus indirect speech?

Comment: "of" is a preposition, not an adverb.

Comment: You mean like "banana peel" and "peel of a banana"?

Comment: Don't you mean *smart corrupt-pattern detection*?